# JavaScript form submit does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following script and it is working well for other browsers, but it does not work in Firefox.

What does not work, is when clicking on the `<a href>`.

How can I solve this?

```js
function submitform() {
    document.forms["serverlogin"].submit();
}
```

```html
<a class="pakb-box" href="javascript: submitform()" target="_blank">
    <p class="pakb-box-icon"><i class="icon-webadresgegevens"></i></p>
</a>
<form id="serverlogin" action="http://example.com" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input name="token" value="1234567890" type="hidden">
    <input name="SESSID" value="1234567890" type="hidden">
    <input name="PHPSESSID" value="1234567890" type="hidden">
    <input value="Open" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Change `id="serverlogin"` to `name='serverlogin'`. By the way, you need to learn AJAX. Also, if that's XHTML, I don't think you can have `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to change id to name, but that does not solve the issue. It still not works in Firefox.

Comment: Why not just use JavaScript the correct way and just create a click Event or something?

Comment: @PunitGajjar Thanks! Strange, it does not work in my browser. It opens a new link, but it does not submit the form. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PHPglue What do you suggest, can you give me an answer?

Comment: To follow up on PHPglue's comment: If you add a unique class or ID to that link, e.g. "clickTarget" then you can attach an event listener (I'll use JQuery since you've tagged your question with it) `$(".clickTarget").on("click", submitform);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

remove the href attribute . and put onclick instead

```
<a class="pakb-box" onclick="submitform()" target="_blank">
```

instead of

```
 <a class="pakb-box" href="javascript: submitform()" target="_blank">
```